# Meteor, How do I change a template (view) on event?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm building an app with two views: home & view list

When the user clicks on a list's name on the home view, it should change to the "view list" template. I've added a session variable called 'view', setting it to 'home' on startup. When a click event is detected on one of the items (list name) on the home screen, it changes the value of view to 'viewList'. Then in the HTML, I have an if statement to show the home template if 'view' is 'home', otherwise show the 'viewList' template.

I can tell the first part works because I'm outputting the value of 'view' and it does output the value "viewList" when you click on a list name, it just doesn't change the template.

What am I missing?

My code:

mylists.js:

```
Lists = new Mongo.Collection("lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup( function() {
    Session.set("view", "home");
  });

  Template.main.helpers({
    view: function () {
      return Session.get("view");
    }
  });

  Template.home.helpers({
    lists: function () {
      return Lists.find({}, {sort: {lastUsed: -1}});
    }
  });

  Template.home.events({
    "submit #new-list": function (event) {
      var name = event.target.listName.value;
      Lists.insert ({
        name: name,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        lastUsed: new Date()
      });
    },
    "click .list-row": function (event) {
        Session.set("view", "viewList");
    }
  });
}
```

mylists.html:

```
<head>
  <title>My Lists</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    {{view}}
    {{#if view "home"}}
        {{> home}}
    {{else}}
        {{> viewList}}
    {{/if}} 
</template>

<template name="home">
  <header>
    <h2>My Lists</h2>
  </header>
    <ul id="lists">
        <li>
            <form id="new-list">
                <input type="text" name="listName" value="My List 1">
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </form>
        </li>
        {{#each lists}}
            {{> list}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="viewList">
  <header>
    <h2>View List</h2>
  </header>
<!-- list details will show here -->
</template>

<template name="list">
    <li class="list-row" id="{{_id}}">{{name}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: what do you want to change? the route? from home  > view list?

Comment: I updated my question after attempting to solve it using a Session variable, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to change from templates view i suggest you tu install the [iron:router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) package.

run

```
meteor add iron:router
```

lester create the `routes.js` on the `/lib` folder

now lets do this step by step.

First create 1 template on `myAppName/client/views/layout.html`

```
<template name="layout">
   {{> yield}}
</template>
```

and update the routes.js with this code.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout' // here we say that layout template will be our main layout
});
```

Now on the same routes.js create this 2 routes.

```
Router.route('/home', function () {
  this.render('home');
});

Router.route('/viewList', function () {
     this.render('viewList');
  });
```

With this if you navigate to `localhost:3000/home` or `/viewList` you will see the html content on there.

NOTES: `<header>` inside the templates you don't need it.

Now this is just an example because i don't really know whats your main idea here.

you are calling `{{#each lists}}` inside the `home` template, so whats the point of having the `viewList` template?

**Now** if you want to create individual and dynamic routes for each list you can try this.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('listViews', {
    path: '/listViews/:_id',
    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('lists')
    },
    data: function(){
      return Lists.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    }
  });
});
```

Now with this, you have dynamic templates for each object on the List collection, if you go to `localhost:300/listView/35dwq358ew` for example you will get render the listView with some data.

you can do stuff like this inside the template list

```
<template name="list">
    <li class="list-row" id="{{_id}}">{{name}}</li>
    <li><a href="/listViews/{{this._id}}">Check this List in detail</a></li>
</template>
```

and the viewList template will look like this.

```
<template name="viewList">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
<!-- list details will show here -->
    {{informationAboutList}}
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Does this mean it's impossible to change templates simply using a click event?

Comment: I don't understand how this changes a template. Also, your previous comment was valuable, I was just asking a question.

Comment: Oh, and to explain a little bit more: This app is a list of lists, like if you had multiple to-do lists. The home screen lists all the to-do lists, and when you tap/click on one, it should bring up that specific to-do list.

Comment: oh well just create dynamic routes with the Router.map option, and put the hrefs to link them

Comment: Sorry for this but what do you mean lib folder? I installed iron router but there is no lib folder in my project.

Comment: the /lib folder is where you the files you want meteor loads very first on when the apps loads, so putting routers and collections declarations on the /lib folder its a good practice, also the code inside lib folder its shared between client and server

Comment: Do you know of any resource I could use about how I'm supposed to structure these folders and what they should be named? I don't know where the lib folder is supposed to go. You also mentioned myAppName/client/views/layout.html ... Does Meteor just look for any and all HTML files in the project folder or does it expect certain names? I wish this were covered in the tutorial...

Comment: Hi @Ethaan, I have a follow-up question for you, if you're around.

Comment: How do we go into private chat again?